# Remove index.php from URLs on WAMP

Tags: url, htaccess

I am trying to remove index.php from my URLs on my local WAMP server using the supported .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I went into General Configuration and removed "index.php" from "Name of your site's index page" and saved. I am running EE on a subdirectory (http://localhost:8080/mysite/), so I removed the "/" before "index.php" in the last line:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works for the home page, but for the rest pages when I click the links (which now have the index.php removed), I get this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /mysite/about-us was not found on this server.

I am still able to access the about-us page at /mysite/index.php/about-us.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I am using the latest version of EE.

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` lines, they are a waste of space and only hide potential problems. Try using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `AllowOverride All` is in the httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf file as per this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906830/135935). You'll need to restart Apache after you make the change.

You may be able to add `AllowOverride All` at the top of your htaccess file too.

Comment: I did try this, and it didn't work. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  # Enable Rewrite Engine
  # ------------------------------
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirect index.php Requests
  # ------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

  # Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
  # ------------------------------
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.*)$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(URL=.*)$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(CSS=.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 
  </IfModule>
```